# $f(x,y)\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{=}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)?$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the joint distriution $F(x,y)$ possess a density $f(x,y)$(with respect to the Lebesgue measure) if for any $x,y$ $$F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{y}f(u,v)dudv.$$ Show that for almost all(with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the plane)$x,y$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y).$$

Actually,the random vector $(X,Y)$ is absolutely continuous,$f$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of  distribution measure $P_{X,Y}$ with respect to Lebesgue measure $\mu$.But how to rigorously proof that $f(x,y)\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{=}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)?$  what about $f(x,y)\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{=}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y)?$

Comment: Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem.

Comment: They are the same !